# USART to 4MBps! how? STM32L151xx

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, usart

How can I increase the USART baud rate to 2Mbps, 3Mbps or 4Mbps. I am using STM32L151RCT6A, I am able to run to 921600. I have set clock with PLL 32MHz. On the datasheet it is given, which shows it is possible, Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: What mode are you trying to use them in? A USART can do uart-type stuff, sync serial, etc, etc, and the 4Mbit/sec may not be possible in all modes.

Comment: I am using usart-RX/TX through interrupts, It might be done using baud rate calculation formula, which using pclk peripheral clock, but need to test this.

Comment: It is explained in great detail in chapter 26.3.4 of the [reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00240193.pdf).  You get to 4Mb with OVER8=1 and USART_BRR=1.  Making that *reliable* and keeping up with the bitrate is untrivial.

Comment: So I have done usart_oversampling8 ENABLE and my pclk clock is 32MHz. I have tried setting usart_brr to 1, but i need some serial terminal utility on windows that can show some prints when I connect to it. Any Idea?

Comment: "usart" is not a mode.  It is a ("Universal") peripheral engine which can operate in either Synchronous or Asynchrnonous mode, but you have to pick one.  As asynchronous mode typically requires an oversampling receive clock, this can complicate high baud rates.  For testing you will need similarly capable hardware - if nothing off the shelf, possibly a second one of your boards (or related more capable discovery series board) backended through USB to a dump or terminal utility on your dev machine.

Comment: Asynchronous operation will not be sustainable at 4Mbps over more than a few centimetres of good quality connection or board trace.  It is probably suited to chip to chip communication on the same board only. Moreover, do the maths, you will be getting an interrupt every 2.5 microseconds - at 33.3MIPS, that 83 instructions.  You will need to use DMA transfer to have a chance of keeping up. You don't have a hope of communicating with a PC at that rate without special hardware.

Comment: ... FTDI's FT232R serial to USB chip can handle 3Mbps, but you's have to place the FT232R close to your processor on the board I would imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datasheet only outlined the specific part and its peripheral set and electrical characteristics. For information on how to use the device you need the [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00240193.pdf).  This gives the following equation for baud rate:

Tx/Rx baud = CK_APB1 / (8 x (2 - OVER8) x USARTDIV)

Where USARTDIV is an unsigned fixed point number that is coded on the USART_BRR register.

- When OVER8=0, the fractional part is coded on 4 bits and programmed by the 
  DIV_fraction[3:0] bits in the USART_BRR register
- When OVER8=1, the fractional part is coded on 3 bits and programmed by the 
  DIV_fraction[2:0] bits in the USART_BRR register, and bit DIV_fraction[3](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF251717) must be kept 
  cleared.

The USARTs are on the APB1 bus, Figure 12 in the reference manual is the clock tree, which shows how the APB1 clock is derived from the PLL clock.  The maximum APB1 clock is 32MHz.  OVER8=1 is required for higher speeds, giving:

baud = 32X10<sup>6</sup> / (USARTDIV x 8).

So USARTDIV = 32X10<sup>6</sup> / (baud x 8)

For 4Mbps therefore, USARTDIV=1 (see table 138 S.No.12 for details). For 2Mps, USARTDIV=2.  To achieve 3Mbps you will have to reduce the APB1 clock to 24MHz and set USARTDIV=1 (see table 131).  But note that the clock rate changes for all other APB1 peripherals too.

The simplest way to correctly program the USART baud rate is via the [STM32L1xx standard peripheral library](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/PF257913).  Also to determine the correct peripheral clock settings (and more), and generate initialisation code, you can use STM's [MicroXplorer](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF251717) tool.

Comment: Thanks! Good answer! I am going to try USART communication between two STM32L151RCT6A board, I will use very small wires to connect USART TXD and RXD, I saw STM32L1xx standard library and I am using that.

Comment: Note that since writing this answer MicroXplorer has been replaced by the more comprehensive STM32CubeMX - although I would still personally recommend the StdPeriph Library over the CubeMX generated code and HAL, it is still a useful clock calculator and pin multiplex conflict checker.